# how to extract words out of a split string

Tags: string, split

Hello i am trying to split a string entered by a user and print each word individually.
For example
Enter input string: (user enters "jill,allen")
First word: Jill
Second word: Allen

```
user_input =(input('Enter input string: \n'))
while ',' not in user_input:
    print('Error: No comma in string.')
    user_input =(input('Enter input string: \n'))
else:
    names = user_input.split()
    print('First word:')
    print('First word:')
```

Comment: You should be explicit about which language you are using in the question. Can we infer Python?

Comment: This seems like you are doing the zylabs lab. Here are some in depth instructions to help you through the lab.

Answer (score 0):

If use python
You must specify a separator in brackets

```
names = user_input.split(',')
for name in names:
    print(name)
```